# Obfuscate or Secure Jmeter Script

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am working on Jmeter Scripts from sometime now, there is a need to secure the Jmeter script and majorly make it unreadable for external stakeholders. My expectation is to obfuscate or deliver the script as some kind of JAR or executable. I need some ideas or workaround to start with.

Thanks

Senz79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to run existing JMeter script from Java code or create a JMeter test purely in Java using [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/) so it is not a problem to create an executable binary which will run your test and obfuscate it.

Example Java code to run a JMeter test:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

import java.io.File;

public class JMeterFromCode {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

        // JMeter Engine
        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

        // Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/tmp/jmeter/bin/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/tmp/jmeter");
        JMeterUtils.initLogging();// you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();


        // Initialize JMeter SaveService
        SaveService.loadProperties();

        // Load existing .jmx Test Plan       
        HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(new File("/tmp/jmeter/test.jmx"));

        Summariser summer = null;
        String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
        if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
            summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
        }

        ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
        logger.setFilename("/tmp/jmeter/test.jtl");
        testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);


        // Run JMeter Test
        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();
    }
}
```

See the following reference material to get started:

- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)
- [Bytecode obfuscation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Bytecode_obfuscation)

Comment: Thanks, was able to execute JMX from java code. Next I want to convert this code to a executable for distribution