# Cannot execute Jmeter test from JAR

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

This is in continuation with the below post

[Obfuscate or Secure Jmeter Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600792/obfuscate-or-secure-jmeter-script)

I am able to create the code to execute Jmeter from JAVA code. I have furhter parametrized it and fetch data at runtime from test file. Also I am able to create the HTML Jmeter report provided by Jmeter 3.0 or above.

The whole framework works best when i execute it from HTML. But the moment I convert it into JAR and try to execute, the Jmeter Test is not triggering.

## Below is the output

```
D:\JmeterTestExecutor>java -jar JmeterTestExecutor.jar
loadJMeterProperties : D:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\jmeter.properties
setJMeterHome : D:\apache-jmeter-3.2
jmxpath : D:\JmeterTestExecutor\AccessGoogle.jmx
aggregatereport : D:\JmeterResult\AccessGoogle.csv
jmeterdashboard : D:\jmeterdashboard
jmeterhtmlreport : D:\jmeterdashboard\index.html
threads : 10
rampupperiod : 1
repeattestcount : -1
duration : 120
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
Initialize JMeter SaveService
Load existing .jmx Test Plan
Run JMeter Test
summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Create dashboard report from CSV

D:\JmeterTestExecutor>
```

============================================================================

As you can see after "Run Jmeter Test" there is no error, but somehow the test do not executes. Please help.

Comment: I think you are missing some library in your project.Did you get any error while exposing the code to runnable jar

Comment: No error but warning. But I am not able to see the warnings in detail